# Importing module in Python keeps giving me an error

Tags: python, api, spotipy

I am trying to use `spotipy` module. On top of my code, I have

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username='username', scope=scope)
```

When I run `"import spotipy.util as util"`, it gives me an error message saying

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy.util'; 'spotipy' is not a package

However, I can see `spotify.util.py` file in my Lib folder locally.

Does anyone know where this error is coming from?

(I am using pythong 3.8 on pyCharm on window)

I already did `pip install spotipy` to my virtual environment and just changed the file name to spotipyPractice.py. However, the problem persists.

Comment: If you named your file `spotipy.py`, pick a different name.

Comment: `spotipy.util.py file` or `spotipy/util.py` (util.py under spotipy folder)?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `$ tree -L 2` or something equivalent?

Comment: @KentShikama I don't understand your question. Should I go on debugger and evaluate `$ tree -L 2`?

Comment: I meant the tree command on a terminal: https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree . Basically I just want to see your directory structure.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Actually he/she was right. I just refactored and it works. Thanks!